# Are Maven dependencies "off site" resources?

Tags: discussion, recommendation-questions

I just came across a question that ends with *I am requesting the Maven coordinates (groupId and artifactId) that will allow me to incorporate this class into my test case.*

On the one hand, this feels like asking for some sort of "3rd party recommendation", on the other hand, the answer (if there is one), would actually be a simple "string" denoting the dependency, that the Maven build system knows to resolve.

So, are such questions off topic (asking for off-site recommendations), or legit?

Comment: Sounds like a really low research effort to me. Google is excellent at telling you what product/library/framework a class can be part of and a simple google for "<name> maven" will provide a link to mvnrepository.com which gives the pom configuration needed to import the dependency.

Comment: @Gimby Basically the question says: I couldn't find anything ... and the one comeback so far is: because that specific setup isn't supported yet (with a link to some bug tracker).

Comment: That does not really match with the generic situation you describe in your question.

Comment: That is why I didnt link to it. I am really more talking about the generic issues. And beyond that, aren't there many people around that "simple google searches" aren't necessary that simple, and therefore that isn't a valid argument to close out questions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A Maven coordinate is a simple string that identifies an off-site resource. A URI is a simple string that identifies an off-site resource. Asking for a URI or URL would be off-topic. I conclude that asking for a Maven coordinate would also be off topic.